# How to add suggested places in Google maps?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, autocompletetextview

I did everything according to the tutorial with Google:
https://developers.google.com/places/training/autocomplete-android

and still have errors in the project

I have a problem in this piece of code:

```
private class PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements Filterable {
    private ArrayList<String> resultList;

    public PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return resultList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int index) {
        return resultList.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        Filter filter = new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                if (constraint != null) {
                    // Retrieve the autocomplete results.
                    resultList = autocomplete(constraint.toString());

                    // Assign the data to the FilterResults
                    filterResults.values = resultList;
                    filterResults.count = resultList.size();
                }
                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                else {
                    notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                }
            }};
        return filter;
    }
}
```

and imports:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.ggimer.dodatki.Animacje;
import com.ggimer.wyznaczanietrasy.R;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.query.Filter;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
```

and errors:

> Multiple markers at this line
>       - The return type is incompatible with 
>        ArrayAdapter.getFilter()
>       - overrides 
>        android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getFilter
>
> Multiple markers at this line
>       - FilterResults cannot be resolved to a type
>       - The method performFiltering(CharSequence) of type new Filter(){} must override or implement a supertype 
>        method
>   Multiple markers at this line
>       - FilterResults cannot be resolved 
>        to a type
>       - FilterResults cannot be resolved 
>        to a type
>
> FilterResults cannot be resolved to a type

I added errors.

Why copying all of the documentation I still have errors?

Comment: what is your specific error?

Comment: I added errors.

Why copying all of the documentation I still have errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter is an [abstract class.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html)

I think you are missing part of it in the anonymous class declaration. Did you check the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Filter.html#filter%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20android.widget.Filter.FilterListener%29)?

Plus, your import: `import com.google.android.gms.drive.query.Filter;`

may be causing part of your problem. I don't think that the two types are compatible:

- ArrayAdapter.GetFilter is expected to return `android.widget.Filter`
- your imports make it seem like you might be returning `com.google.android.gms.drive.query.Filter`

So, double check that. Try removing `import com.google.android.gms.drive.query.Filter;` and see if that fixes it.